# How can I view the channels that I have been added to recently on Slack?

Tags: slack

How can I view the channels that I have been added to recently on Slack?

I searched the question on Google, and looked at [slack.com/help](https://slack.com/help), but I didn't see any answer.

---

When I get added to a Slack channel, I get notified in Slack as follows:

[image: Channels list: the "expre*" channel has a green "1" bubble next to it]

(expre* if the Slack channel I got added to in this example).

Comment: This question would be improved if you provided an example of what you expect to see and other useful details.  It seems a bit specific to administrative actions divorced from actual conversations.  I expect what you are talking about is restricted to admins exposing it for the channels they manage and using the API to extract that info or actively tracking notifications you receive if you receive them the moment you are added.  This question is not great as it stands, and if you really want an answer you should provide additional details.

Comment: @Blindspots thanks, I'd be happy to clarify but I'm not sure what to add. I sometimes get added to some channels. Then after a few days or weeks, I want to find some of these channels but I forgot their names

Comment: How you know you get added would be a good starting point

Comment: @Blindspots I believe it appears as an unread message on Slack.

Comment: @Blindspots When I get added to a Slack channel, I get notified in Slack as follows: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyFa3.png (expre* if the Slack channel I got added to in this example).